CORBA implementation to replace the one removed from Java 11
Java 11 removed support for Common Object Request Broker Architecture (CORBA) that was bundled in previous versions.
Oracle offered the technology for a third-party to adopt.
 Has any alternative become available to support CORBA in Java apps?

This was asked on sister site StackOverflow.com but was closed as off-topic there.

Glassfish Corba
GlassFish-Corba is a CORBA ORB implementation.
See:

Project page
Source code on Github
Maven repository

